# MongoAlchemy ObjectIdField resolution

Tags: python, mongoalchemy

If I have a Model that contains an ObjectIdField to another model, I would normally (django) use a `property` to create a getter and the reference would be transparent in usage. Like so:

```
class Image(db.Document):
    name_full  = db.StringField(required=True)
    name_thumb = db.StringField(required=False)
    source     = db.StringField(required=False)

class Product(db.Document):
    name        = db.StringField()
    description = db.StringField(required=False)
    image_id    = db.ObjectIdField(required=False)

    def _get_image(self):
        try:
            return db.query(Image).filter(mongo_id=self.image_id)[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None
    image = property(_get_image)
```

Though, in practice I get this error when trying to access it from a template:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/products/'+product.image.name_thumb) }}">

UndefinedError: 'app.models.Product object' has no attribute 'image'
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: I suspect my query to retrieve the Image isn't the best either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. It seems that my mistake was in the function itself, not the declaration of the property. Once I used a `session` instead of `db` it started working. I also shortened the property declaration to just use `@property` instead.

```
from mongoalchemy.session import Session
session = Session.connect('flask-test')

....

    @property
    def image(self):
        try:
            return session.query(Image).filter({"mongo_id":self.image_id})[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None
```